# Use theme to make small Activity

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I've meet the app with activity looks like dialog: it has small size and does not overlap previous activity.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ToolActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth" >
    </activity>
```

Why does it work? And where can I read about this? What section of documentation I have to read to understand this mechanics and to know other possibilities?

Comment: maybe activity attribute <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" /> is what Your lookig for....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Yep. But why it works?

Comment: it´s hard to tell why....it´s the android architecture. That´s like to ask, how a chicken can lay eggs. Maybe You could read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html